# JavaScript: Preloading images function - Usage, DOM ready & SEO?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader, preload, image-preloader

With the help of Google I've written a small preloader script:

```
var i = 0;

function preloader() {

    imageObj = new Image();

    images = [
        'some/image1.jpg', 
        'some/image2.jpg',
        'some/image3.png',
        'and.png',
        'so.jpg',    
        'on.png'
    ];

    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i ++) {

      imageObj.src = images[i];

    }
}
```

This function must be called in the `head` of my HTML file for maximum effect, right? Do I really need to declare `var i = 0;`? How can I fire another function once the preloading is complete?

Also, I would like to ask how to implement this function in running websites. Let's say I have a page that has 100 `img` tags. I guess I have to copy and paste the source into the `images` array by hand, right? Because to do that with a loop, the DOM needs to be ready which again means that the images have already started loading?

Does preloading affect SEO?

If there is a better jQuery way of preloading I would be ok with that.

Comment: the way I understand it, preloading is only used for elements that are NOT in the DOM (yet). elements in the DOM get loaded anyway, and the event for when they have loaded is $(document).ready() (assuming jQuery). The actual effect towards anything depends on how (and why) you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're assigning the image SRC to the same variable, the each new request will cancel the previous because it has not completed loading.

You can use an array for this as well:

```
imageObj = [];

...your code...

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i ++) {
      imageObj[i] = new Image()
      imageObj[i].src = images[i];
    }
```

No, this will not affect SEO because the scrapers are looking at the TEXT of your page, not the images. You can run this before the DOM is ready because you're not manipulating the DOM - all images are in memory.

jQuery is simply made of JavaScript and does not really have anything that would speed the efficiency of this simple block of code.

Comment: There's no reason to store the image in an array (`imageObj`), unless it needs to be accessed later...

Comment: The reason for this is to ensure that it loads. Otherwise the request for the image will get cancelled the next iteration of the loop and no pre-loading will occur.

Comment: No it won't, because the fact that you use `new Image()` on every loop ensures a new image and new (not overwritten) request is started. Why wouldn't it load? I've used preloading like this without the array and it's worked fine

Comment: Yes, but the OP is using a new image OUTSIDE of the loop.

Comment: Right, so I agree that you need to use a `new Image()` inside of the loop, but I don't see a reason to put that image in a new array `imageObj`. You should be able to do `var newImage = new Image(); newImage.src = images[i];`